# Xamarin.Forms UWP - Requesting to enable app to run at startup

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am wanting my app to launch when the user logs into Windows. Currently, I can do this by opening up Task Manager > Startup > and setting 'Enable' for my app. I am wanting to do this within my app though, and have followed [this guide](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/08/01/configure-app-start-log/). However, when requesting the app to run at startup, it always throws the exception below:

```
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.
```

This doesn't make sense to me, as my app only calls `RequestEnableAsync()` if the `StartupTaskState` is `Disabled`, as seen in my code below:

```
private async Task<bool> SetLaunchOnLogin_UWP_Async(bool shouldLaunchOnLogin)
{
    try
    {
        var startupTask = await StartupTask.GetAsync("MyProjectStartupId");

        switch (startupTask.State)
        {
            case StartupTaskState.Disabled:

                Debug.WriteLine("Startup is disabled. Will ask");
                // The code reaches here, but always throws an exception 
                // when calling RequestEnableAsync():
                var newState = await startupTask.RequestEnableAsync()
                return newState == StartupTaskState.Enabled;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(
            "SpecificPlatformFunctions_UWP - SetLaunchOnLogin_UWP_Async ERROR: " 
            + ex.ToString());
    }

    return false;
}
```

And the full error output:

```
Startup is disabled. Will ask
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
SpecificPlatformFunctions_UWP - SetLaunchOnLogin_UWP_Async ERROR: System.Exception: The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007139F)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MyProject.UWP.DependencyServices.SpecificPlatformFunctions_UWP.<SetLaunchOnLogin_UWP_Async>d__13.MoveNext()
```

The code above is called via a `DependencyService`, when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this simply by running the code on the main thread. IE, wrapping it inside of `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => { ... });`